# How can I reduce code duplication in two classes that extend different base classes?

Tags: c#, oop, xamarin.android

I have a class that has to extend `Activity`, e.g.

```
BaseActivity : Activity { }
```

and another class that has to extend `ListActivity`, e.g.

```
BaseListActivity : ListActivity {} // ListActivity in turn extends Activity
```

Both of these classes have some of the same methods, e.g.

```
OnCreate(Bundle bundle), OnStart(), OnStop()
```

with the exactly the same implementation in both, e.g.

```
BaseActivity : Activity {

    public bool isBound = false;
    public MyServiceBinder binder;
    MyServiceConnection _myServiceConnection;
    MyReceiver _myReceiver;
    internal Intent _myServiceIntent;   

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        _myServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MyServiceCls));
        _myReceiver = new MyReceiver();

        _myServiceConnection = LastNonConfigurationInstance as MyServiceConnection;

        if (_myServiceConnection != null)
            binder = _myServiceConnection.Binder;
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();

        var intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MyServiceCls.MyUpdatedAction) { Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority };
        RegisterReceiver(_myReceiver, intentFilter);

        _myServiceConnection = new MyServiceConnection(this);
        Application.Context.BindService(_myServiceIntent, _myServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);

        StartService(_myServiceIntent);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();

        if (isBound)
        {
            Application.Context.UnbindService(_myServiceConnection);

            isBound = false;
        }

        StopService(_myServiceIntent);

        UnregisterReceiver(_myReceiver);
    }
}
```

and

```
BaseListActivity : ListActivity {

    public bool isBound = false;
    public MyServiceBinder binder;
    MyServiceConnection _myServiceConnection;
    MyReceiver _myReceiver;
    internal Intent _myServiceIntent;   

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        _myServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MyServiceCls));
        _myReceiver = new MyReceiver();

        _myServiceConnection = LastNonConfigurationInstance as MyServiceConnection;

        if (_myServiceConnection != null)
            binder = _myServiceConnection.Binder;
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();

        var intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MyServiceCls.MyUpdatedAction) { Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority };
        RegisterReceiver(_myReceiver, intentFilter);

        _myServiceConnection = new MyServiceConnection(this);
        Application.Context.BindService(_myServiceIntent, _myServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);

        StartService(_myServiceIntent);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();

        if (isBound)
        {
            Application.Context.UnbindService(_myServiceConnection);

            isBound = false;
        }

        StopService(_myServiceIntent);

        UnregisterReceiver(_myReceiver);
    }
}
```

The difference lies in the usage of both of these. For example

```
MyActivity : BaseActivity 
{ /* this overrides the methods and does things differently */}
```

and

```
MyListActivity : BaseListActivity 
{ /* this overrides the methods and does things differently */}
```

Ultimately my problem is that I don't want to have the same code copied in the `BaseActivity` and `BaseListActivity` classes. What's the best way to resolve this where I can still have the overrides that are needed to execute the required functionality, without having the code duplication?

*note:* some of you may recognise this as an Android project - it is. It's being built with Xamarin (aka Monodroid), which is why it's in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the common code into its own class and call the methods of the class in your base classes overrides. You won't be able to get rid of these.

Comment: Wasn't the issue that they share no common base class?

Comment: @spender: Sure. I didn't say that he should extract the common code into a *base* class. Composition is the relevant keyword here.

Answer (score 0):

Spin the common method into a static method of a helper class and supply all the variables that the common code relies upon as parameters.